# mod_rewrite con plugin weblogic proxy

Tags: apache, weblogic, mod-rewrite

Estoy configurando Apache para conectar el servidor de aplicaciones weblogic con apache, cosa que ya funciona pero se necesita que las urls que vienen del bakend de weblogic que sean:

**http://dominio.com/weblogic/strataVal/services/apiRest**

sean

**http://dominio.com/strataVal/services/apiRest**

La razón es porque los clientes de fronend de Angular tienen configuradas las rutas de los Api Rest para que funcionen con el nombre del proyecto, en este caso, strataVal, y luego /services/.

Mi configuración de apache es:

```
 <Location /weblogic/strataVal>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule ^strataVal/services/apiRest$ /weblogic/strataVal/services/apiRest [L]
 </Location>
```

Pero cuando accedo a la url http://dominio.com/weblogic/strataVal/services/apiRest, sigue funcionando y no la que debería funcionar http://dominio.com/strataVal/services/apiRest.

Comment: Una reescritura así no impide de ninguna manera que accedan al recurso original, es de esperarse que te funcione `/weblogic/...`. Y en cuanto a lo que no funciona, ¿Será porque estás accediendo a una URL que tiene algo más después de `.../apiRest`? ¿Podrías poner ejemplos de lo que no te está funcionando? ¿Qué error te está dando? ¿Qué aparece en el log de Apache?

Comment: Accedo a la url: http://dominio.es/strataVal/services/apiRest y me dice The "requested URL /strataVal/services/apiRest was not found on this server." En el access.log de apache dice: 1.42.5.45 - - [27/Feb/2018:08:06:25 +0100] "GET /strataVal/services/apiRest HTTP/1.1" 404 539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0" Y no pongo nada después de apiRest, es un Api Rest de pruebas, para que yo pueda configurar el apache :(.

Comment: Elimina el `<Location>` que está mal

Comment: Entonces ... ¿dónde meto esa configuración?, la tenía metida en la carpeta de sites-available de mi servidor debian y activada.

Comment: Todo esto viene de la instalación de un plugin de oracle para conectar weblogic a Apache:    `LoadModule weblogic_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/apacheWeblogic/lib/mod_wl_24.so

<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
        WebLogicHost localhost
        WeblogicPort 7003
</IfModule>

<Location /weblogic>
        SetHandler weblogic-handler
        Debug ERR
        WLLogFile /var/log/apache2/weblogic_proxy.log
        PathTrim /weblogic
#       PathPrepend /
</Location>`

Comment: Directamente en el .htaccess, fuera de este `<Location>`. Si estás intentando que coincida con `/strataVal`, jamás te va coincidir cuando está dentro de `/weblogic`